# Jquery ui selectable causing problems with hyper links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a small problem with the Jquery ui selectable function.

```
$("#test").selectable({
    filter:'label',
    stop: function() {        
        $(".ui-selected input", this).each(function() {
            this.checked= !this.checked
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/APfcf/

The HTML links within the DIV tag "test" do not respond when clicked. While the HTML link outside of the DIV tag behaves normally.

I'm trying to get those links within the DIV tag working again. They seem to respond if you right click and open in new tab or window, but left clicking doesn't do anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cancel to make sure the selectable doesn't apply to your anchor tags:

```
$("#test").selectable({
    filter:'label',
    cancel: 'a',
    stop: function() {        
        $(".ui-selected input", this).each(function() {
            this.checked= !this.checked
        });
    }
});
```